# Xen kernel can't see 2 disks of 6 of 1TB, does it have a limitation?

Tags: xen, hard-drive, xenserver, gentoo

```
Linux gentoo-xen 2.6.18-xen-r12 #3 SMP Tue Oct 5 09:28:53 PDT 2010 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5506 @ 2.13GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

I have 6 disks of 1 TB and i can't see all of them only 4, can anyone give me an ideea what can i do ?

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                886G  4.4G  836G   1% /
/dev/sda3             886G  4.4G  836G   1% /
rc-svcdir             1.0M   44K  980K   5% /lib64/rc/init.d
shm                   7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1             917G  200M  871G   1% /home2
/dev/sdc1             917G  200M  871G   1% /home3
/dev/sdd1             917G  200M  871G   1% /home4
```

The hardware is Dual xeon E5506 processors on a supermicro X8DTL mobo

```
4.346585] ata3.00: ATA-8, max UDMA/133, 1953525168 sectors: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
[    4.346588] ata3.00: ata3: dev 0 multi count 16
[    4.352861] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    4.352867] scsi3 : ata_piix
[    4.352875] PM: Adding info for No Bus:host3
[    4.510584] ata4.00: ATA-8, max UDMA/133, 1953525168 sectors: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
[    4.510587] ata4.00: ata4: dev 0 multi count 16
[    4.516848] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    4.516861] PM: Adding info for No Bus:target2:0:0
[    4.516905]   Vendor: ATA       Model: SAMSUNG HD103SJ   Rev: 1AJ1
[    4.516910]   Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 05
[    4.516920] PM: Adding info for scsi:2:0:0:0
[    4.517452] SCSI device sde: 1953525168 512-byte hdwr sectors (1000205 MB)
[    4.517460] sde: Write Protect is off
[    4.517461] sde: Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    4.517478] SCSI device sde: drive cache: write back
[    4.517514] SCSI device sde: 1953525168 512-byte hdwr sectors (1000205 MB)
[    4.517521] sde: Write Protect is off
[    4.517522] sde: Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    4.517532] SCSI device sde: drive cache: write back
[    4.517534]  sde: sde1
[    4.524551] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi disk sde
[    4.524855] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[    4.524874] PM: Adding info for No Bus:target3:0:0
[    4.524928]   Vendor: ATA       Model: SAMSUNG HD103SJ   Rev: 1AJ1
[    4.524933]   Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 05
[    4.524946] PM: Adding info for scsi:3:0:0:0
[    4.525216] SCSI device sdf: 1953525168 512-byte hdwr sectors (1000205 MB)
[    4.525227] sdf: Write Protect is off
[    4.525228] sdf: Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    4.525242] SCSI device sdf: drive cache: write back
[    4.525280] SCSI device sdf: 1953525168 512-byte hdwr sectors (1000205 MB)
[    4.525286] sdf: Write Protect is off
[    4.525289] sdf: Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    4.525301] SCSI device sdf: drive cache: write back
[    4.525302]  sdf: sdf1
[    4.532691] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi disk sdf
[    4.533010] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[    4.977669] scsi: <fdomain> Detection failed (no card)
[    5.030479] GDT-HA: Storage RAID Controller Driver. Version: 3.05
[    5.030635] GDT-HA: Found 0 PCI Storage RAID Controllers
[    5.372350] Fusion MPT base driver 3.04.01
[    5.372358] Copyright (c) 1999-2005 LSI Logic Corporation
[    5.579176] Fusion MPT SPI Host driver 3.04.01
[    5.881777] ieee1394: Initialized config rom entry `ip1394'
[    6.166745] ieee1394: sbp2: Driver forced to serialize I/O (serialize_io=1)
[    6.166748] ieee1394: sbp2: Try serialize_io=0 for better performance
[    6.428866] md: md driver 0.90.3 MAX_MD_DEVS=256, MD_SB_DISKS=27
[    6.428872] md: bitmap version 4.39
[    6.431518] md: raid0 personality registered for level 0
[    6.495979] md: raid1 personality registered for level 1
[    6.570270] raid5: automatically using best checksumming function: generic_sse
[    6.575523]    generic_sse:  6608.000 MB/sec
[    6.575526] raid5: using function: generic_sse (6608.000 MB/sec)
[    6.596226] raid6: int64x1   1835 MB/s
[    6.613231] raid6: int64x2   1773 MB/s
[    6.630256] raid6: int64x4   1675 MB/s
[    6.647296] raid6: int64x8   1027 MB/s
[    6.664267] raid6: sse2x1    3578 MB/s
[    6.681268] raid6: sse2x2    4207 MB/s
[    6.698280] raid6: sse2x4    4625 MB/s
[    6.698281] raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 (4625 MB/s)
[    6.698285] md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
[    6.698286] md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
[    6.698288] md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
[    6.781090] md: raid10 personality registered for level 10
[    7.007043] Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - version 7.1.9-k4
[    7.007046] Copyright (c) 1999-2006 Intel Corporation.
[    9.229465] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
[    9.229476] EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the drives not being mounted, are they even being seen by the kernel? Check dmesg output to see how many drives are being reported by the BIOS. I have encountered this issue a couple of times in the past, I can admit I forgot to check the BIOS settings of either the motherboard or controller, and also I've had hard drives that weren't seated properly behave like this.

If they are being reported in the BIOS and dmesg is picking them up at boot, do they have valid partitions/file systems on them, do they have appropriate /etc/fstab entries?

You are suspecting the Xen kernel to have something to do with this, if you boot the system with a standard kernel do you see the drives?

Comment: Yes with a standard kernel it seems they are being detected unfortunately